# Why are gnosis safe contracts not optimized when compiled?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

this is a question about Safe Contract. Compiling the [GnosisSafeL2.sol](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/contracts/GnosisSafeL2.sol) contract confirmed that it was close to the EVM contract max size of 24.5KiB. And when I run the hardhat optimizer 200 times, I saw that the byte code size was reduced by almost half.
Looking at the singletons distributed on each mainnet, optimizing was not carried out. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for not using the Optimizer is that it is an unaudited piece of software which may introduce unwanted bugs like "[Optimizer Bug Regarding Memory Side Effects of Inline Assembly](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2022/06/15/inline-assembly-memory-side-effects-bug/)". You can find other occurrences on Google too.

Also, the contracts are already pretty well optimized; the difference is negligible if you compare the gas usage with and without the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

The focus is easy debugging and development, not optimization.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Usually better to include a reference for the answer, or your affiliation if for example you wrote the contracts being asked about.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is very specific for one or two developers, who compiled this contract, it is unlikely that you get an answer on a public forum. The only way to get an answer is to ask directly from Gnosis Safe devs what was in their mind when they did it.